# Bootstrap datetimepicker cut off inside of tab-content box

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker. Please see the pics here first:

1. The datetimepicker is within the Bootstrap tab-content control and is cut off by the upper margin. 
   **screenshot of without br tags**
   [image]
2. A layer of br tags add padding, thus allowing the full datetimepicker to reveal itself.
   **screenshot of br tags included**
   [image]

Here is the markup of the form without the br tags below form-group:

```
<form class="form-horizontal mt-sm" action='' method="POST">
    <fieldset>    
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="expiration-date" class="control-label col-md-3">Expiration Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-10"><input type="text" id="expiration-date" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here are the scripts:

```
<script src="/lib/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
```

Comment: please add fiddle.

Comment: yeah fiddle would be better to play but you can try z-index as well on date picker.

Comment: The tabs container probably has `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden`. Somehow the datepicker generated in that div instead of generated to the `body`. Again, fiddle will be great ;)

Comment: @maverickosama92 Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5HDu/280/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `z-index` of your tabs are higher than the date-picker UI. So to resolve this you must increase the z-index of the date picker UI.

```
.datepicker {
    z-index: 1151;
}
```

Make sure you change the selector to be more specific on required `.datepicker` elements. Also make sure that this style takes the priority. In my case I had to use `z-index: 1151 !important;` But I don't recommend it unless you are able to get this working without the `!important`.

Comment: @omrakhur not sure with the number exactly But this is what worked for me. I think long back I took this number from else where when I faced similar issue..  Did this work for you?

Comment: It's not working. I have tried placing the style within the input, as well as within the div but still no luck. I also increased the index to 100000, but doesn't work

Comment: @omrakhur did you use `z-index: 1151 !important;` ?

Comment: Yes with that as well. I also looked into Chrome's errors. And it says over there that "autosize not defined in forms-elements.js https://jsfiddle.net/qck86vd6/

Comment: I am sure this is because the element in which the date picker is added to is in inside a div that has overflow hidden or scroll. It doenst matter what z-index you have if the popup element is added as a child of that container unfortunately.